# Error 'cannot be initialized in a query result' when trying to get data with Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, jqgrid, entity-framework-4.1

**ISSUE:**

I have an asp.net mvc 3 app. I'm using EF 4.1 and trying out jqGrid.   I'm trying to get data for my jqGrid using the GridData method below.  I get the following error on the group of data starting at 'var jsonData = new...'.  Any ideas?

**ERROR:**

{"The array type 'System.String[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. 
Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' instead."}

**GridData Method:**

```
    public JsonResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {                        
        var result = from a in db.t_harvest_statistics_elk
                     where a.year == "2008" && a.unit_number == 1
                     orderby a.id
                     select a;


        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = result.Count();   // context.Questions.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var questions = result.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from question in questions
                select new
                {
                    i = question.id,                                                
                    cell = new string[] { SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)question.id), SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)question.total_rec_days), question.year }

                }).ToArray()
        };

        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

**HERE IS AN EXAMPLE THAT DOES WORK**

```
public JsonResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var context = new HaackOverflowDataContext();
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = context.Questions.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var questions = context.Questions.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from question in questions
                select new
                {
                    i = question.Id,
                    cell = new string[] { question.Id.ToString(), question.Votes.ToString(), question.Title }
                }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix the code will be to use something like the following

```
// to be able to use ToString() below which is NOT exist in the LINQ to Entity
// so we should get the data from the database and save the result locally before
// the next step. One can use .ToList() or to .AsEnumerable(), but one should
// choose only the fields of questions which we will need later
var queryDetails = (from item in questions
                    select new { item.id, item.total_rec_days, item.year }).ToList();
var jsonData = new {
        total = totalPages,
        page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (
            from question in queryDetails
            select new
            {
                id = question.Id,
                cell = new [] {
                    question.Id.ToString(),
                    question.total_rec_days.ToString(),
                    question.year.ToString()
                }
            }).ToArray()
    };
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Your current code contain some small problems like the usage of `i = question.id` instead of `id = question.id`.

I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) and download [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridExportToExcel.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) which contains more recent and extended code.

Comment: I had to use 'queryDetails.AsEnumerable()' to make the above example work. It does work thanks.

Comment: @KeelRisk: You are welcome! I didn't tested the code which I wrote :-)

Comment: My bad...you had it correct!!  You do not need AsEnumerable().

Comment: @KeelRisk: OK, no problem. I think the both ways will produce the same results. I used `ToList()` to show, that from the point we have real data and not only the SELECT statement typical for `IQuerable` or `AsQueryable`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonData = new {
    total = totalPages,
    page,
    records = totalRecords,
    rows = (
        from question in queryDetails
        select new
        {
            id = question.Id,
            cell = new IComparable[]{

                question.Id.ToString(),
                question.total_rec_days.ToString(),
                question.year.ToString()
            }
        }).ToArray()
};
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try modifying your code like :

```
rows = ( 
                from question in questions.AsEnumerable() //AsEnumerable() is added to switch to LINQ to Entites to eager load the data.
                select new 
                { 
                    i = question.id,                                                 
                    cell = new string[] { SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)question.id), SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)question.total_rec_days), question.year } 

                }).ToArray()
```

Because the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487158.aspx/) says that : "You cannot call this function directly. This function can only appear within a LINQ to Entities query." (Though the next line is little confusing in documentation)

Comment: `questions.AsEnumerable()` is nice short, but it will produce `SELECT * FROM Questions` instead of `SELECT id, total_rec_days, year FROM Questions`. So it's better to use `(from item in questions select new { item.id, item.total_rec_days, item.year }).AsEnumerable()` or just simple `(from item in questions select new { item.id, item.total_rec_days, item.year }).ToList()` instead of `questions.AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use custom functions inside direct queries to you database. Instead you can do something like this:

```
rows = questions.AsEnumerable() 
//or select just that you want  questions.Select(q=> new {g.Id, q.Votes,q.Title})
       .Select(p=> new {
                         id = p.Id,
                         cell = new string[] { SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.id), SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.total_rec_days), p.year }
                }).ToArray()
```

That should work.

Comment: `questions.AsEnumerable()` is nice short, but it will produce `SELECT * FROM Questions` instead of `SELECT id, total_rec_days, year FROM Questions`. So it's better to use `(from item in questions select new { item.id, item.total_rec_days, item.year }).AsEnumerable()` or just simple `(from item in questions select new { item.id, item.total_rec_days, item.year }).ToList()` instead of `questions.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Did you even read my answer, in the comment i said "or select just what you want  questions.Select(q=> new {g.Id, q.Votes,q.Title})" meaning he can first select what he needs than use AsEnumerable() and the other code on this selection.

Comment: OK, I understood you in another way. Just one `AsEnumerable` *or* `questions.Select(q=> new {g.Id, q.Votes,q.Title})` is not enough. One should first `questions.Select(q=> new {g.Id, q.Votes,q.Title})`, then  call `AsEnumerable()` and then use `Select` one more time where one can use `ToString()`. I think that one will can't able to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` which works with LINQ to Entities queries, but not with `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Read the comment please!!  rows = questions.Select(p=> new {p.Id, p.total_rec_days,p.year}).AsEnumerable()
       .Select(p=> new {
                         id = p.Id,
                         cell = new string[] { SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.id), SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.total_rec_days), p.year }
                }).ToArray()