# ASP.NET MVC 3 jqGrid : grid renders json data in browser

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have problem with rendering jqGrid in ASP.net MVC 3.
Responsibility of ProductInfo action is to display list of product along with other latest product information (**in ProductInfo view**). When user click on any product link, ProductModelList action fetch all modellist of selected product & pass it to **ProductModelList view** where all jqGrid codes is written. But It renders row json data in browser as given bellow

{"total":null,"page":null,"records":9,"rows":[{"id":4,"cell":["3","Hyundai Accent"]},{"id":5,"cell":["3","Hyundai Santro"]},{"id":6,"cell":["3","Hyundai Santa Fe"]},{"id":7,"cell":["3","Hyundai i10"]},{"id":8,"cell":["3","Hyundai i20"]},{"id":9,"cell":["3","Hyundai Tucson"]},{"id":10,"cell":["3","Hyundai Verna Fluidic"]},{"id":11,"cell":["3","Hyundai EON"]},{"id":12,"cell":["3","New Hyundai Sonata"]}]}

following are controller and view:

```
public class Product : Controller
    {
        **//used to view product list**
        public ActionResult ProductInfo()
        {
            ViewBag.ModelNameList = ModelRepository.GetModelName();
            ViewBag.ModelVersionNameList = ModelVersionRepository.GetModelVersionName();
            return View(new NewCarSearchContainer());
        }
        **//used to view modellist using jgGrid**
        public JsonResult ProductModelList(int brandId, string sidx, string sord, int? page, int? rows)
        {


            var result = new
            {
                total = (ModelRepository.GetModelByBrandId(brandId).Count() + rows - 1) / rows,
                page = page,
                records = ModelRepository.GetModelByBrandId(brandId).Count(),
                rows = (from model in ModelRepository.GetModelByBrandId(brandId)
                       select new
                       {
                           id = model.ModelId,
                           cell = new string[] { model.BrandId.ToString(), model.ModelName }
                       }).ToList()
            };

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
}


ProductModelList View:
=====================


<table id="jqgProducts">
</table>
<div id="jqgpProducts">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jqgProducts').jqGrid({
            //url from wich data should be requested
            url: '/Product/ProductModelList',
            //type of data
            datatype: 'json',
            //url access method type
            mtype: 'GET',
            //columns names
            colNames: ['id', 'ModelId', 'BrandName'],
            //columns model
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'ModelId', index: 'ModelId', width: 40, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'BrandName', index: 'BrandName', width: 40, align: 'left' },
                          ],
            //pager for grid
            pager: $('#jqgpProducts'),
            //number of rows per page
            rowNum: 10,
            //initial sorting column
            sortname: 'ModelId',
            //initial sorting direction
            sortorder: 'asc',
            //we want to display total records count
            viewrecords: true,
            //grid height
            height: '100%'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please guide me?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The `'id'` from the JSON data will be used to assign `id` attribute of the rows of the grid (`id` of `<tr>` elements). The ids **must be unique** on the page. All your current data contains the same id (id=3).

I would recommend you to download some working example (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935)) and modify it corresponds to your requirements.

Comment: Oleg, thanks for your reply. I could find out the problem. I have [product] controller and two actions [productlist] and [models] within the product controller. [ProductList] Action displays list of product in ProductListView. In ProductListView when any product link is being clicked it call [models] action of [product] controller. In [modelsview] load all jqGrid code is written. I think as i am redirecting it show row json data in browser. if i do whole the thing in one view it work fine? Please guide me while redirecting from one view to another how in 2nd we can populate a jqGrid?

Comment: @Paul: If I understand you correct you should open the View which you posted in the text of your question. The vies should contains empty `<table>` and the pager `<div>`. Additionally on the view should be loaded JavaScript which convert the `<table>` and the `<div>` to grid and fill it with JSON data returned by '@Url.Action("Models")'. I am not sure, but probably it would be better to have *one* page with two grids: one with products and another with product details. To tell the truth I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but all it sounds not like the main question which you asked

Comment: Oleg, suppose i have two View(ProductInfo,ProductModelList) and both are belonged to one controller Product. ProductInfo view contains product list along with other latest news of product. If user click any product(hyperlink) i want to redirect user to ProductModelList view to show all the model of that product. I cannot club these two view in one because both view contain other valuable information apart from listing(some of them are static). I have written all codes to fetch modellist as per productid in ProductModelList action of product controller. I have used RAZOR as view engine.