# How to export the Jqgrid Filtered data into Excel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, jqgrid, export-to-excel

I made a Jqgrid for dispalying database with filterToolbar option using Asp.net
Now As per my need i want the filtered data to get exported into .excel formate ..

Here i am posting my code....

```
var categoriesStr = ":All;1:vikas;2:Ankur";
    $(function () {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['UserID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'EmailID'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'UserName', width: 100, sortable: true, formatter: 'select',stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: categoriesStr} },
                    { name: 'FirstName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'MiddleName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'LastName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'EmailID', width: 150, sortable: true },
                   // { name: 'ContactNo', width: 150, sortable: true },
                    //{ name: 'Address', width: 150, sortable: true }
                ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'UserID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            autowidth:true

            //caption: 'JSON Example'
        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false,search:false });

       $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#UsersGrid-pager',{ caption: "Filter", title: "Toggle Searching Toolbar",buttonicon: 'ui-icon-search',onClickButton: function () {$("#UsersGrid")[0].toggleToolbar(); }
});
```

plz Guys Help me to complete my task .Thanx in advance...

Comment: what you tried so far ?  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should read **UPDATED** part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935). You can download [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExportToExcel.zip) which I created for the answer. I recommend to use [Open XML SDK 2.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) (or [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en) if you can use .NET 3.5 only) to export data to excel. More common way of usage HTML table as pseudo-Excel export can produce wrong import on data. I described such problems in details in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11263503/315935).

I suppose that **UPDATED** part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935) provides exactly what you need (or you can easy modify the demo to have the solution which you need).