# Printing grid view data horizontally

Tags: asp.net, printing, datagridview, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a requirement where i have a asp.net grid view with a header and some rows. There should be a print option by which i should be able to print the rows of the grid view horizontally on a paper size of 4*3. If the number of records exceed the width, those should be carried over to next sheet. Right now, i am trying with crystal reports but i am facing a lot of limitations in implementing this. I am open to use any other tools(aspose, jqgrid may be or anything else?).

Any suggestion, what could be the most efficient way to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid is pure **JavaScript** solution. One can't implements the requirements which you described inside of the language.

I would suggest you to implement exporting of the data of the grid to Excel for example. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) for more implementation details. Excel allows to format and print tables like you need.