# Export To Excel filtered data with Free jqgrid 4.15.4 in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a question regarding Export to Excel in free-jqgrid 4.15.4. I want to know how to use this resultset `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"FirstName","op":"eq","data":"Amit"}]}` into my Business Logic Method.

Just for more clarification, I've using **OfficeOpenXml** and if I don't use filtered resultset(aforementioned) it is working fine and I'm able to download file with full records in an excel sheet. But I'm not sure what to do or how to utilize the resultset `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"FirstName","op":"eq","data":"Amit"}]}`

If required I can share my controller and BL code.

I have added a fiddle which shows implementation of Export to Excel button in jqGrid pager.

Before coming to here, I've read and tried to understand from following questions:

1] [jqgrid, export to excel (with current filter post data) in an asp.net-mvc site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005312/jqgrid-export-to-excel-with-current-filter-post-data-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site)

2] [Export jqgrid filtered data as excel or CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227898/export-jqgrid-filtered-data-as-excel-or-csv)

Here is the code :

```
$(function () {
"use strict";
var mydata = [
    { id: "10",  FirstName: "test", LastName: "TNT", Gender: "Male" },
     { id: "11",     FirstName: "test2",    LastName: "ADXC", Gender: "Male" },
     { id: "12",     FirstName: "test3",    LastName: "SDR", Gender: "Female" },
     { id: "13",     FirstName: "test4",    LastName: "234", Gender: "Male" },
     { id: "14",     FirstName: "test5",    LastName: "DAS", Gender: "Male" },
];
$("#list").jqGrid({
data: mydata,

    colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Gender'],
     colModel: [
        {
            label: "Id",
            name: 'Id',
            hidden: true,
            search: false,
        },
        {
            label: "FirstName",
            name: 'FirstName',
            searchoptions: {
                searchOperators: true,
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le','ni', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'],
            }, search: true,
        },
        {
            label: "LastName",
            name: 'LastName',
            searchoptions: {
                searchOperators: true,
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'ni', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'],
            }, search: true,
        },

        {
            label: "Gender",
            name: 'Gender',
            search: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: 'Male:Male;Female:Female' }, stype: 'select',

        },
        ],
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastsel) {
            jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel);
            jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
            lastsel = id;
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function (id) {
        if ($('#list').getGridParam('records') === 0) {

            //$('#grid tbody').html("<div style='padding:6px;background:#D8D8D8;'>No records found</div>");
        }
        else {
            var lastsel = 0;
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel);
                jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
                lastsel = id;
              }
            }
        },      
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    width: 'auto',
    height: '150px',    
    emptyrecords: "No records to display",
    iconSet:'fontAwesome',
    pager: true,
    jsonReader:
    {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "Id"
    },

});
jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "fa-table",
    title: "Export To Excel",
    onClickButton: function (e) {
        var projectId = null;
        var isFilterAreUsed = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'search'),
           filters = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters;   
        var Urls = "/UsersView/ExportToExcel_xlsxFormat?filters="+ encodeURIComponent(filters); //' + encodeURIComponent(filters);/
        if (totalRecordsCount > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: Urls,
                type: "POST",
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { "searchcriteria": filters, "projectId": projectId, "PageName": "MajorsView" },
                //datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (true) {
                        window.location = '/UsersView/SentFiletoClientMachine?file=' + data.filename;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#resultDiv").html(data.errorMessage);
                        $("#resultDiv").addClass("text-danger");
                    }                       
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    common.handleAjaxError(ex.status);                        
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            bootbox.alert("There are no rows to export in the Participant List")
            if (dialog) {
                dialog.modal('hide');
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ap43xecs/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exist many option to solve the problem. The simplest one consist of sending ids of filtered rows to the server instead of sending `filters` parameter. Free jqGrid supports `lastSelectedData` parameter and thus you can use `$('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData')` to get the array with items sorted and filtered corresponds to the current filter and sorting criteria. Every item of the returned array should contain `Id` property (or `id` property) which you can use on the server side to filter the data before exporting.

The second option would be to implement server side filtering based on the `filters` parameter, which you send currently to the server. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) (see `FilterObjectSet`) provides an example of filtering in case of usage Entity Framework. By the way, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935) contain code, which I used for exporting grid data to Excel using Open XML SDK. You can compare it with your existing code.

In some situations it could be interesting to export grid data to Excel *without* writing any server code. The corresponding demo could be found in [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/417) and **UPDATED** part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28644753/315935).

Comment: Hello @Oleg, How to handle **Maximum request length exceeded** when passing `var filters= $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData')` as a param in ajax call?      
Like `data:{ searchcriteria: JSON.stringify(filters)},`

Comment: @Chandan: I'm not sure what you mean. `var filters= $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData');` can be used to get all local data of the grid. It makes no Ajax call. I suppose that the error "Maximum request length exceeded" shows on the problem on some restriction of your server code and not on any restriction on the client side.